# if $p\mid u_m$, $m\mid n$, $p\mid u_n/u_m$, prove that $p\mid n/m$

Tags: number-theory, lucas-numbers

If we have that $p\mid u_a$, $b\mid a$, and $p\mid u_a/u_b$, prove that $p\mid n/b$, assuming that $u_a$ and $u_b$ are terms in the linear recurrence for the Lucas Sequence.

I've tried looking at the characteristic polynomial and using the discriminant in divisibility comparisons, but I haven't be able to get that far. This is one idea of where to go:

$u_n/u_m = (a^n-b^n)/(a^m-b^m) = K_{n/m}$

The characteristic polynomial of $K_{n/m}$ is $(a^m, b^m)^2$, but that's as far as I know.

If anyone has ideas for how to approach the proof, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you add the tag Lucas number? Is the linear recurrence is for the Lucas sequence? I think you need to clarify your question more. Please tell us what is the connection of this problem with Lucas numbers.